# .htaccess rewrite getting url not found

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am trying to rewrite URL's using .htaccess methods. This is working on localhost when XAMPP is used, but when I put it on the server it just doesn't.

Here is an example of the code used:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
DirectorySlash Off

RewriteRule ^contacts?$ contacts.php
RewriteRule ^example?$ tester.php?number=1
RewriteRule ^anotherexample?$ tester.php?number=2
```

I get this error message:

```
The requested URL /AMENPTHOME/hostnd/b/5/6/b56a95b8c/www/htdocs/public/new/produto_individual.php was not found on this server.
```

Can someone help?